# startActivityForResult from adapter inside Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-camera

I have a fragment and I filled a RecyclerView in it, a post contains a camera and I need to take the information it brings when I take the photo. I do not know how to do it.

Please help.

This is mi code:

**PostAdapter.java**

```
        public HeaderViewHolder (View itemView) {
        super (itemView);
        this.mCamera = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivCamera);
        mCameraPhoto = new CameraPhoto(itemView.getContext());
        this.mCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    ((Activity) v.getContext()).startActivityForResult(mCameraPhoto.takePhotoIntent(), CAMERA_REQUEST_ASIST);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e("Error camera permission", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    String photoPath = mCameraPhoto.getPhotoPath();
    for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Log.d("Result in fragment",":D --> "+photoPath);
    }

}
```

**MyFragment.java**

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d("Result in fragment",":D");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Pass fragment into PostAdapter's constructor.

```
class PostAdapter {
   private Fragment fragment;

   public PostAdapter(Fragment fragment) {
      this.fragment = fragment;
   }
}
```

then inside onclick

```
this.mCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try{
                fragment.startActivityForResult(mCameraPhoto.takePhotoIntent(), CAMERA_REQUEST_ASIST);
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("Error camera permission", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You also need to remove the `onActivityResult` override from your Activity as well. The `FragmentActivity` class (or `AppCompatActivity` if using v7) already handles this for you.

Comment: i attemp pass the fragment to adapter, but show error.! :(, "final Fragment homeGcFragment_ = new Fragment();"
--"mRecyclerGCPost.setAdapter(new PostHeaderAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), data, homeGcFragment_));"

Comment: in fragment class, did you call PostAdapter adapter = new PostAdapter(this);

Comment: mRecyclerGCPost.setAdapter(new PostHeaderAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), data, this));

Comment: following error "Fragment HomeGcFragment_{56503bd} not attached to Activity"

Comment: - "HomeGcFragment_ fragment = null;"
- "fragment = new HomeGcFragment_();"
- "mRecyclerGCPost.setAdapter( new PostHeaderAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), data, fragment) );"

Comment: You said you have a fragment and you fill it with recycler view. Are you calling setAdapter in MainActivity or MyFragment? If you call setAdapter from MyFragment you do not need to make a new HomeGCFragment object.

Comment: i have a "MyFragment" in this fill the recycler and the adapter, the adapter call to camera.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144876/discussion-between-miller-mosquera-and-denominator).

Answer (score 0):

Use one of getFragmentById() or getFragmentByTag() methods to get the reference to your fragment

Comment: where put the fragment id?

Comment: When you create a fragment you do smth like this
=====>
  transaction.replace(R.id.content, fragment, "fragmetTAg");
                    transaction.commit();

Then you can get an instance of the fragment by using getFragmentByTag()

Answer (score 0):

You can get the information of the photo you took as the following.

**In your fragment**

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_ASIST ){
                String photoPath = mCameraPhoto.getPhotoPath();
                try {
                    // Update data in your Custom RecyclerView Adapter 
                    // and call notifyDatasetChanged

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }//end if resultCode
    }
```

And more information https://github.com/kosalgeek/PhotoUtil/blob/master/README.md

Comment: HI! this code throw a exception, a error in "Bundle extras = data.getExtras" , the object is null

Comment: Show this method body, mCameraPhoto.takePhotoIntent() please.

Comment: Is a library, not have body!

Comment: do you use this library? https://github.com/kosalgeek/PhotoUtil/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Yes, Exactly. PhotoUtil!

Comment: I think it will be helpful for you to show me all source code. If you don't solve the problem, please let me know.^^